# Bug error: trying to set asp.net radiobuttonlist selected item from codebehind return an error

Tags: c#, asp.net

When using the following code, this error is returned:
*'rblPermisSejourA' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.*

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblPermisSejour" runat="server"
DataSourceID="EntityDataSourcePermisSejour" DataTextField="Libelle"
DataValueField="Id" AppendDataBoundItems="True" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
<asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="" Value="-1">Aucun</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>

<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblPermisSejourA" runat="server"
DataSourceID="EntityDataSourcePermisSejour" DataTextField="Libelle"
DataValueField="Id" AppendDataBoundItems="True" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
<asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="" Value="-1">Aucun</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>

protected void ws2_OnDeactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  rblPermisSejourA.SelectedValue = rblPermisSejour.SelectedValue;
}
```

Note that "rblPermisSejour" is in a wizard step and "rblPermisSejourA" in another wizard step that is not yet activated (no id and no title for the step in witch there is the "rblPermisSejourA"). When this step is activated, all is working well. 
But with the same code and same operation **with another RadioButtonList it's working very well** and this **within the same context** (wizard step not activated).

Comment: The error states that the value you have selected in rblPermisSejour does not exist in rblPermisSejourA. Is this correct? Can you provide an example of what is in the two lists when the function is called?

Comment: @DavidAGibson: Yes, this is what the error meens. It's like if the dynamic data of list A are not loaded. An exemple: `rblPermisSejourA.SelectedValue = "-1"` works, but not `rblPermisSejourA.SelectedValue = "1"`.
Exemple of the supposed same content of the two lists:
`<asp:ListItem Value="1">A</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="2">C</asp:ListItem>`
In fact if you go one time to the wizard step of list A, the data are correcly loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is THE solution:

> if (rblPermisSejourA.Items.Count <= 1) 
>       rblPermisSejourA.DataBind(); //added to correct the bug 
>   rblPermisSejourA.SelectedValue = rblPermisSejour.SelectedValue;

Comment: Two lines of code added without changing anything else.
As the RadioButtonList Control "rblPermisSejourA" only load the item in the front code after the affectation, I force the data to be bound before with a single DataBind() as the EntityDataSource is already defined and linked in the front code.
I test if those supplementary items (i.e. from DataBase) are not already loaded with a condition about the number of elements of the concerned list.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment

```
<asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="1">A</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="2">C</asp:ListItem>
```

you have BOTH items selected="true" so calling .SelectedValue may be a problem as it won't know which value you mean. Are  these the list items form rblPermisSejourA or rblPermisSejour? If you edit your question to add both lists we can see what this line

```
rblPermisSejourA.SelectedValue = rblPermisSejour.SelectedValue;
```

is trying to do and figure out your error.

EDIT

Have you tried something like

```
rblPermisSejourA.Items.FindByValue(rblPermisSejour.SelectedValue).Selected = true;
```

Comment: Sorry, I corrected the data list in my comment, there is no other "selected" items.

Comment: The both lists are connected exactly to the same data source:
"EntityDataSourcePermisSejour":
`<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSourcePermisSejour" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="name=PAOffresEntities" 
            DefaultContainerName="PAOffresEntities" EnableFlattening="False" 
            EntitySetName="PermisSejour">
        </asp:EntityDataSource>`
  Do you want full code?

Comment: Hi Cisnarf, I don't think it's about the data source, did the line above work? If not then it maybe that the items in rblPermisSejour have been cleared when you are trying to set rblPermisSejourA. you may need to store the selected value in a variable that will last between wizard steps - although I think this sounds unlikely.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your suggestion, that is good, but you must have in mind that if you try to select a value in the A list, you got the same error: `rblPermisSejourA.SelectedValue = "1"' for example. It's seems that the A list is not loaded correctly. But what should I do?

Comment: Hi David, I tried your proposition `rblPermisSejourA.SelectedValue = rblPermisSejour.SelectedValue;`: same problem, same error. Sorry.

Comment: I also try this, instead adding the list item in front code:
`ListItem listItem = new ListItem("Aucun", "-1");
rblPermisSejourA.Items.Insert(0, listItem);`
No way: exactly same problem and error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
rblPermisSejourA.SelectedValue = rblPermisSejour.SelectedItem.Value;
```

Comment: I just tried it now: same problem, same error. In fact, the problem is that rblPermisSejour doesn't load full data at first time. I don’t know why, because other controls in the concerned step are loading correctly.

Comment: I just find something interesting: if I delete the line `<asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="" Value="-1">Aucun</asp:ListItem>` in rblPermisSejourA it works fine. But in fact, I need this special line, witch is added in front code until now.

Comment: debug your code and make sure that dropdown is filled with data before you are initializing the above process... Also make sure that some other function is not clearing/Re-Initializing your dropdownlist at runtime..

Comment: No way... The debug mode reveal just the same thing as I told before: only one item is loaded, the one defined in front code. If you delete this item, the list (i.e. rblPermisSejourA) is loaded correctly with it's five elements. And it works well. But anyway, I need to add the "null" element!